# How to allow the special character to exiting regular expression

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to allow the special characters to input string. 
where as I am using :

```
public const string state = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9- '.,&()]+)$";
```

This regular expression which doesn't allowing me to add the special char. What should be the modification in this expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to allow `@`, just put it within the square brackets, for example at the end:

```
public const string state = @"^([a-zA-Z0-9- '.,&()@]+)$"; 
                                                  ^
```

Be sure *not* to insert it where you'd break a range (e.g. `a-z` shouldn't become `a-@z`). or create another range (e.g. `0-9- '` becoming `0-9@- '`).

`[ ... ]` is a character class and anything inside will be able to match.